# Post Image to Telegram Channel via Telegram Bot

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem with sending a photo to channel using a bot. I try to find an example how to do this. I have this code:

```
SendPhoto sendPhoto = new SendPhoto();
sendPhoto.setCaption("My Caption!");
sendPhoto.setNewPhoto(new File("/Users/user/Desktop/photo.png"));
sendPhoto.setChatId("@test_channel");
```

Also, I have `apiToken`. But I can't understand how to send this photo to channel. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Sean I don't have any error because I don't know how to init action of posting image to channel via bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a photo to a channel first you should add your bot to the channel as an administrator and then you should find out the channel ID of your channel because you will need that when you want to send the image knowing these all you need to do is:

```
try 
{
 sendPhoto(sendPhoto); // Call method to send the photo with caption
} 
catch (TelegramApiException e) 
{
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way, you can also send the image to your bot and extract the file ID of your image and try sending it using file ID. This way your bot will not use your local server.